# Is it possible to select multiple values for an XPM Footprint?

Tags: experience-manager, session-preview, footprint

I have created a custom Footprint representing the customer's segment (not related to Audience Manager segments) and its currently working fine set up as a `FootprintRadio` control, allowing the Editor to select a segment from a predefined list of values and preview content variations on the Page based on this segment.

A site visitor can be in multiple segments, so I was wondering how/if I can get this working in XPM Preview? Ideally there would be a `FootprintCheckbox` control, but this doesn't seem to be an option. I was thinking of implementing it myself (based on [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-406B3CFA-EA48-4511-ABB8-06F44A2B32EC)) but am not sure if I can pass a multi-value claim to the ADF Claimstore via the Footprint cookie?

Comment: You may need to write your own footprint control, but I don't know if that's supported

Comment: It is supported (even somewhat documented - see docs link)